# jQuery filter() compatibility with Internet Explorer 6-7-8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have an ajax call in my page, i use for this particular task the jQuery library. In the response of the ajax call i'd like to parse the response message.

The problem is that this code gives me an error message at IE 6-7-8 (**the weirdness is that IE 9 works perfectly and Firefox works perfectly**):

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Timestamp: Mon, 12 Aug 2013 08:20:03 UTC


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 94
Char: 4
Code: 0
```

Any idea is highly appreciated. Looks like this this line is generating error:

```
response_str = $(server_response).filter("#response").val();
```

I copy my code related part:

```
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'ajax.php',
processData: 'false',
data:{
    data1: 'val1'
    ajax:'true'
        },
dataType: "html",
contentType: ''application/x-www-form-urlencoded''
    })
  .done( function(server_response) {
       //the following line generate error
       response_str = $(server_response).filter("#response").val();
          }
     })
}');
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? jQuery 2 does not support IE 8 and older.

Comment: Your code has a lot of stuff like this: `type:''POST'',`. This can't possibly be the actual code you're running.

Comment: @Jonathan: thanks i check the version

Comment: @Micheal Geary: You haver right, this is a pl/sql code which is genrated in to the html, so '' should be ' in the html code (pretty weird i know)

Comment: The version number is 1.10.1.

Comment: Please split the line into several statements (unchaining) so we can see which part of it throws the error. And which method does the message mention?

Comment: Thanks Bergi, however with the help of @Spudly i managed to found the problem which was -> response_str = $(server_response).filter("#response").val();

should be--->
var response_str = $(server_response).filter("#response").val();

Answer (score 1):

Why not just `find()` it?

```
response_str = $(server_response).find("#response").val();
```

---

```
response_str = $(server_response).filter(function(i, el){
    return $(el).is('#response');
}).val();
```

The code above assumes that there only is one element with the id "response".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Here is a very good description about find vs filter: http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/difference-between-filter-and-find-in-jquery/
Please check it out, but basicly the answer is because i have also siblings nodes in my response and not only childs...

Comment: @czupe I don't really see the problem. You're looking for an element with a certain id somewhere in the html response. You will find it with both `find` and `filter`, regardless of the html structure. I will update the answer with another `filter` option since you seem to prefer that.

Comment: I deeply appreciate your work so i will upvote it, but i kindly ask you to check this example out: http://www.mkyong.com/wp-content/uploads/jQuery/jQuery-find-filter-example.html

And i can assure you that i was first trying with find and it was not work (could not found the element:()

Comment: :second example seems fine, but as i told in another comment the problem is solved ( var was missing and because of another javascript engine ie 9 can parse what ie8- could not)
Regards.

Comment: @czupe Ok, I just assumed that you had defined the variable earlier